# Fetch data from context that is not yet committed. CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, magicalrecord

I have created multiple instances of an `NSManagedObject` entity(for example Car: `NSManagedObject`) in the default `NSManagedObjectContext` using `MagicalRecord`.

I didn't save the context. Is there a way to execute a fetch request and obtain the data that is already in persistent state **and** the data not yet committed that was added in default context ?

Comment: That should be the default behavior, unless you set includesPendingChanges=NO for the fetch request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fetched. Please check Apple docs at https://developer.apple.com/reference/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext:

> An object that meets the criteria specified by request (it is an instance of the entity specified by the request, and it matches the request’s predicate if there is one) and that has been inserted into a context but which is not yet saved to a persistent store, is retrieved if the fetch request is executed on that context.

Answer (score 0):

not as far as I know... you can fetch it all and then look at the objects objectID to decide which one was already saved.

```
id all = [ctx fetch..]; 
id savedOnly = [NSMutableArray array];
for(id o in all) {
    if([[o objectID] isTemporary] == NO) {
        [savedOnly addObject:o];
    }
}
```

OR change your code to use to contexts -- that may be better :D

---

OR **maybe** use a predicate like:

```
savedOnly = [ctx fetchWithPredicate:@"... self.objectID.isTemporary=NO"];
```

MIGHT work... don't know

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about the same managed object context - yes, you should be able to get also those objects, which are not committed. This is the default behavior. The managed object context contains also the uncommitted  objects, i.e. the objects which are not saved yet in the persistent store.